# University hierarchy in drupal 7

Tags: users

I'm completely new to Drupal. I've been reading a lot of questions but I could not find anything that fits my needs. I need to create an internal site for my university.

There is one person that is the university coordinator (UC). This person should be able to add a department coordinator (DC) in a way that there are two fields in the form: department name (text field) and the email of DC. After submitting the form a new user should be created with the username the same as name in the email (before @) with a random password that is sent to the email address. This user should be below UC in the hierarchy. DC then should be able to add institute coordinators (IC) the same way. Each DC should be able to manage their ICs. How can I set-up this scenario? Which modules should I install? Is it possible without writing code?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Questions asking to recommend or find a module are off-topic for us. You need to find a module that is closer to your needs; then you can ask how to achieve what you want with that module, or ask in which way that module can be extended to achieve what you want.

Comment: Drupal can achieve this functionality, but (more) easily without your exact user interface. For example look at the LDAP module if your users are already in ldap groups and their existance is already in LDAP. To break up the site into sections and groups of users see the Organic Group module. If you can live with how-drupal-does-it largely you dont need to write code. If you want a custom UI and workflow -- then enjoy learning coding your snowflake application.

Answer (score 1):

1. We need `university coordinator` role, we can create it in `People > Permissions > Roles`.
2. Next, we create `department coordinator`. We do it just like in first step.
3. `University coordinator` can make a new user and set a role to it. So we create user `DC`, set the e-mail `dc@example.com` and set the password `loremipsum`. Standalone Drupal has not possibility to generate a random password.

Then, to let `department coordinator` manage the `insitute coordinators` you should install [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole). One problem - this module don't let you to manage content created by the users.